# How to make a new line in a list of objects where the self instance is present in Python?

Tags: python, newline

I am trying to print out a list holding objects and their attributes where every element in the list is printed in a new line. However, I don't know how or where to add '\n' when appending the object.

*client_manager.py*

```
class ClientManager:
    # Constructor for the client list
    def __init__(self):
        self.__client_list = []

    def add_client(self, first_name, last_name, title, preferred_pronouns,
                   date_of_birth, occupation, account_balance, overdraft_limit):
        self.__client_list.append(Client(first_name, last_name, title, preferred_pronouns,
                                         date_of_birth, occupation, account_balance, overdraft_limit))
```

*test.py*

```
def test_manager():
    manager = ClientManager()
    manager.add_client("John", "Smith", "Mr", "He/him", "06/08/2003", "student", 455.0, 100.0)
    manager.add_client("Sam", "Mason", "Mr", "He/him", "01/09/2002", "student", 455.0, 100.0)
    manager.print_client_list()

test_manager()
```

I would like to get an output like this:

```
[Client(John, Smith, Mr, He/him, 06/08/2003, student, 455.0, 100.0),
 Client(Sam, Mason, Mr, He/him, 06/08/2003, student, 455.0, 100.0)]
```

Instead of

```
[Client(John, Smith, Mr, He/him, 06/08/2003, student, 455.0, 100.0), Client(Sam, Mason, Mr, He/him, 06/08/2003, student, 455.0, 100.0)]
```

I tried  using join but that doesn't work and raises an error:

self.__client_list = '\n'.join(self.__client_list)

So how can you implement \n or should you use another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply iterate on your `self.__client_list` attribute:

```py
def print_client_list(self):
    for client in self.__client_list:
        print(client.__dict__)
```

Outputs:

```
{'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'title': 'Mr', 'preferred_pronouns': 'He/him', 'date_of_birth': '06/08/2003', 'occupation': 'student', 'account_balance': 455.0, 'overdraft_limit': 100.0}
{'first_name': 'Sam', 'last_name': 'Mason', 'title': 'Mr', 'preferred_pronouns': 'He/him', 'date_of_birth': '01/09/2002', 'occupation': 'student', 'account_balance': 455.0, 'overdraft_limit': 100.0}
```

If you wish to only get the values, you could do like this:

```py
def print_client_list(self):
    for client in self.__client_list:
        for k, v in client.__dict__.items():
            print(v, end=" ")
        print()
```

Outputs:

```
John Smith Mr He/him 06/08/2003 student 455.0 100.0 
Sam Mason Mr He/him 01/09/2002 student 455.0 100.0
```

Comment: Just a little correction `def print_client_list(self)`

Comment: Yep, this works just fine. Didn't think about just changing the print method.

Comment: The output differs from the stated requirement

Comment: The stated requirements was to have the output on multiple lines, and I think this is achieved :)

Answer (score 0):

You achieve this by overriding the *str* method of the Client class. Something like this:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, title, preferred_pronouns, date_of_birth, occupation, account_balance, overdraft_limit):
        self._first_name = first_name
        self._last_name = last_name
        self._title = title
        self._preferred_pronouns = preferred_pronouns
        self._date_of_birth = date_of_birth
        self._occupation = occupation
        self._account_balance = account_balance
        self._overdraft_limit = overdraft_limit
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Client({self._first_name}, {self._last_name}, {self._title}, {self._preferred_pronouns}, {self._date_of_birth}, {self._occupation}, {self._account_balance:.1f}, {self._overdraft_limit:.2f})'

class ClientManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self._client_list = []

    def add_client(self, *args):
        self._client_list.append(Client(*args))
    
    def print_client_list(self):
        cstring = [str(client) for client in self._client_list]
        print('['+',\n '.join(cstring)+']')

manager = ClientManager()
manager.add_client("John", "Smith", "Mr", "He/him", "06/08/2003", "student", 455.0, 100.0)
manager.add_client("Sam", "Mason", "Mr", "He/him", "01/09/2002", "student", 455.0, 100.0)
manager.print_client_list()
```

**Output:**

```
[Client(John, Smith, Mr, He/him, 06/08/2003, student, 455.0, 100.00),
 Client(Sam, Mason, Mr, He/him, 01/09/2002, student, 455.0, 100.00)]
```